# Sharing iOS runtime between macs

Tags: ios, macos, simulator, xcode9

Have you ever wondered: Where are the iOS simulator runtimes located on the File System other than the most recent version of them?

I do as I need to avoid downloading some of them again in my work place so I went into looking for the path to just copy them into a flash memory and put them in my other macs, with no success...

Answer (score 0):

Sure I know! Quit Xcode and simulator app, next, if you are using Sierra, you just have to go to: `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` and there you will find the associated runtimes to each one of the iPhone/iPad simulators.

For High Sierra users you have to dig into Xcode package contents reaching this path: `Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`

Once there, you are going to copy or paste the runtime of your choice. Then you should open Xcode again and voila! You are going to see your available simulators in all runtimes stored in the previously mentioned location. In case it doesn't show anything just close Xcode and open it again, sometimes it gets lost a little bit before acknowledge the runtimes it has available.

Comment: You could also try to symlink that location to something like Dropbox on both machines. Then they will sync in real time.